Are there any specific examples of overlapping impact and volcanic craters on Earth?
This answer to Can a crater form inside another crater in Astronomy SE points out that in addition to impact-on-impact double craters, there can be volcanic double craters, and even a one on the other (though no example could be thought of there).
So, I'd like to know if there are specific examples of overlapping impacts and volcanic craters on Earth.
Asked separately in Astronomy SE: Are there any specific examples of overlapping impact and volcanic craters on astronomical bodies beyond Earth?

It's a bit of a stretch, but the Pilansberg volcanic structure lies on the outer edges of where the Vredfort crater would be,  if it hadn't been entirely eroded away.  And Pilanesberg isn't really a crater either.   But that's the best I could come up with.  Most volcanic structures are very young and the cratering rate on Earth is rather low (and craters tend to get eroded after only a short time.

Yes in fact it may be fairly common for larger impact craters since they fracture and weakend the crust. Plus the impact itself will melt rock meaning by definition each large impact crater has som vulcanism.
Pit-floor craters (not to be confused with normal pit craters) are a well know form of impact crater that has a magma chamber in the center and are found on several planets. https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-1-4614-9213-9_268-1
https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2016JE005085
